# Datetime to string: differents behavior depending on the converted datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, tostring, date-format

I use this C# code to convert a datetime to a string:

```
MyDatetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

it works, but not every time. What do I mean?

If the input datetime is, for example, `2016-10-19 17:27:41.727`, I get the string as expected, `19/10/2016 17:27`. If the day in datetime (and/or the month) has only one digit, I get something weird.

If the input is `2016-01-07 14:58:13.560`, I get `1/7/2016` and if it is `2016-10-26 17:14:16.000` I get `10/6/2016`.

Do you know why? How can I always set a leading zero for days and months with only one digit? And, further, why I don't see the time part in the date I wrote as examples?

**UPDATE**

[image: This is my input].

Some datetime fields from a SQL Server database (this is SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: The input values are of type String or of type DateTime?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal example that reproduces this problem?   Right now I don't see how you're having the issue as described.

Comment: In case you parse this input, most probably you parse it wrong. MyDatetime.Day probably will return also wrong value

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The inputs are datetime object from my database

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this

Comment: `var dateTimeStr = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-10-19 17:27:41.727");` this will give you the DateTime along with rather it's `AM or PM` also do a MSDN Google Search on `Convert.ToDateTime` and it's overloads

Comment: Specify an appropriate `CultureInfo` value in the `ToString()` call as the `IFormatProvider` and you'll get more consistent results, for example:

`MyDatetime.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");`

Comment: I ran you code on my local machine and it worked fine and generated expected out put. I used ADO.NET to retrieve the value and used SQLDataReader.GetDateTime to get the values in DateTime variable. Can you check what DateTime value you are getting for `2016-01-07 14:58:13.560` via EF? I assume that `MyDateTime` is the actual value retrieved from the db in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your DateTime already has invalid value (day and month are mixed)

```
new DateTime(2016, 01,  07,14,58,13,56).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

returns `07-01-2016 14:58`.

Take a look how do you read this DateTime value from the database. I believe the problem is there. (for example [SqlDataReader.GetDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Comment: I read the value with Entity Framework and if I navigate the datetime object with the debug it seems correct

Comment: I don't get how you get the different output. Try to specify the culture like `            myDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @PieroAlberto what output do you get for above code?

Comment: It seems the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

When you input a date as "XXXX-XX-XX" it assumes you're using the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

Just look at your input-output and you can see the pattern.
A lot of people in programming (that I work with) use this format because it is auto-filtering without any punctuation (20170102 will always go after 20161231, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime method works in conjunction with the computer language. If your computer (or server) is in English (or vice versa) and you pass an American non-standard date format, you will have problems like this.
If you are using a web application, configure the correct language in web.config